# SQL hierarchy - getting newest grandchild

Tags: sql, h2

I have a H2 database with a LEFT JOIN query on `Bird` which returns all birds along with the newest `Health_Check.Catch_Date`. I want to extend this query and include in the results newest PIT.ID, PIT.CODE and TRANSMITTER.IDc, TRANSMITTER.CHANNEL which are related to `Health_Check`.

**Note**: not every `Health_Check` has a relationship to a Transmitter or PIT.

[image]

A few notes about how the data is structured.

- Most birds have several health checks;
- Not every health check has a associated PIT or TRANSMITTER;
- The newest Health_Check for a bird may not contain a PIT or TRANSMITTER;
- Most birds have one PIT;
- Most birds have a few Transmitters;
- The date the Transmitter or PIT was attached is based on the related Health_Check.Catch_Date;
- Most of my queries will require returning a Bird with the newest Health Check, PIT and Transmitter.

The SQL to get the newest HEALTH_CHECK is:

```
SELECT b.NAME, b.ID as birdId, hc1.CATCH_DATE, hc1.id as healthCheckId
FROM BIRD b
         LEFT OUTER JOIN
     (  HEALTH_CHECK hc1
         INNER JOIN
         (
             SELECT BIRD_ID, MAX(CATCH_DATE) AS MAX_DATE
             FROM HEALTH_CHECK
             GROUP BY BIRD_ID
         ) hc2
         ON hc2.BIRD_ID = hc1.BIRD_ID AND
            hc2.MAX_DATE = hc1.CATCH_DATE
         )
     ON hc1.BIRD_ID = b.ID;
```

**Question**: how can I also return in the results the most recent PIT and TRANSMITTER?
NB: The newest PIT and TRANS is often not on the newest HealthCheck. I am open to a schema change/adding a second relationship but I must be able to determine which HealthCheck a PIT and TRANS was attached in.

As an example results would look like:

```
BIRD.ID  |  BIRD.NAME  | NEWEST HEALTH CHCECK | PIT.ID | PIT.CODE | TRANS.ID | TRANS.CHNL |
---------|-------------|----------------------|--------|----------|----------|------------|
   1     |    Bob      |    2022-03-01        |  AB001 |     3    |    2     |     40     |
   2     |    Jim      |      NULL            |  NULL  |    NULL  |   NULL   |    NULL    |
   3     |    Jane     |    2022-01-02        |  DC123 |     2    |    3     |     50     |
```

Comment: it is the same as with the last check in, but if you don't have that may pits and transcation per chein if use window functions https://www.h2database.com/html/functions-window.html or the same Max comnstruct you already have

Comment: @nbs I would If I understand how, but now there is another level of nesting (unlike health check)

Comment: can you tell how many transmitter there are actually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution can be, to get the highest ID from every TRANs ANd PIT, i thinl that is the only ORDER that ic could find

Row_number would give every row for a specific chekc id, and the nimber 1 should be last one(ORDER BY ID DESC), it counts for every channel a new

```
SELECT b.NAME, b.ID as birdId, hc1.CATCH_DATE, hc1.id as healthCheckId
,PIT.ID , PIT.CODE,TRANS.ID , TRANS.CHANNEL
FROM BIRD b
         LEFT OUTER JOIN
     (  HEALTH_CHECK hc1
         INNER JOIN
         (
             SELECT BIRD_ID, MAX(CATCH_DATE) AS MAX_DATE
             FROM HEALTH_CHECK
             GROUP BY BIRD_ID
         ) hc2
         ON hc2.BIRD_ID = hc1.BIRD_ID AND
            hc2.MAX_DATE = hc1.CATCH_DATE
         )
     ON hc1.BIRD_ID = b.ID
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT ID, CODE,HEALTH_CHECK_ID
FROM
 (SELECT ID , CODE,HEALTH_CHECK_ID
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY HEALTH_CHECK_ID ORDER BY ID DESC) rn FROM PIT) Pt
WHERE rn = 1) PIT ON PIT.HEALTH_CHeCK_ID = hc1.ID

LEFT JOIN
(SELECT ID, CHANNEL,HEALTH_CHECK_ID
FROM
 (SELECT ID , CHANNEL,HEALTH_CHECK_ID
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY HEALTH_CHECK_ID ORDER BY ID DESC) rn FROM PIT) tr
WHERE rn = 1) TRANS ON TRANS.HEALTH_CHECK_ID = hc1.ID;
```

If there is a 1:1 relaionship you need only to join them,

```
SELECT b.NAME, b.ID as birdId, hc1.CATCH_DATE, hc1.id as healthCheckId
,PIT.ID , PIT.CODE,TRANS.ID , TRANS.CHANNEL
FROM BIRD b
         LEFT OUTER JOIN
     (  HEALTH_CHECK hc1
         INNER JOIN
         (
             SELECT BIRD_ID, MAX(CATCH_DATE) AS MAX_DATE
             FROM HEALTH_CHECK
             GROUP BY BIRD_ID
         ) hc2
         ON hc2.BIRD_ID = hc1.BIRD_ID AND
            hc2.MAX_DATE = hc1.CATCH_DATE
         )
     ON hc1.BIRD_ID = b.ID
LEFT JOIN
 PIT ON PIT.HEALTH_CHeCK_ID = hc1.ID

LEFT JOIN
 TRANS ON TRANS.HEALTH_CHECK_ID = hc1.ID;
```

if you need another heahc_ckes tarns and Pit that are not in the latest healthcheck, you need to add to the sunselect of the first query all healch ckes of that bird

```
SELECT b.NAME, b.ID as birdId, hc1.CATCH_DATE, hc1.id as healthCheckId
,PIT.ID , PIT.CODE,TRANS.ID , TRANS.CHANNEL
FROM BIRD b
         LEFT OUTER JOIN
     (  HEALTH_CHECK hc1
         INNER JOIN
         (
             SELECT BIRD_ID, MAX(CATCH_DATE) AS MAX_DATE
             FROM HEALTH_CHECK
             GROUP BY BIRD_ID
         ) hc2
         ON hc2.BIRD_ID = hc1.BIRD_ID AND
            hc2.MAX_DATE = hc1.CATCH_DATE
         )
     ON hc1.BIRD_ID = b.ID
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT ID, CODE,HEALTH_CHECK_ID,BIRD_ID
FROM
 (SELECT ID , CODE,hc3.BIRD_ID,HEALTH_CHECK_ID
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY HEALTH_CHECK_ID ORDER BY hc3.CATCH_DATE DESC) rn FROM HEALTH_CHECK hc3 JOIN PIT ON hc3.ID = PIT.HEALTH_CHeCK_ID
WHERE hc3.BIRD_ID = hc1.BIRD_ID) Pt
WHERE rn = 1) PIT ON PIT.BIRD_ID = hc1.BIRD_ID

LEFT JOIN
(SELECT ID, CHANNEL,HEALTH_CHECK_ID,BIRD_ID
FROM
 (SELECT ID , CHANNEL,HEALTH_CHECK_ID,BIRD_ID
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY HEALTH_CHECK_ID ORDER BY hc4.CATCH_DATE DESC) rn FROM HEALTH_CHECK hc4 JOIN PIT ON hc4.ID = PIT.HEALTH_CHeCK_ID
WHERE hc4.BIRD_ID = hc1.BIRD_ID) tr
WHERE rn = 1) TRANS ON TRANS.BIRD_ID = hc1.BIRD_ID;
```

Comment: Is it possible to order by the CATCH_DATE on HEALTH_CHECK that each PIT or TRANS has arelation to?

Comment: No, every table needs it won order, as you don't have a 1:1: relation ship between Health_check and Pit for examlple, you can order it a every HEaLTH_CHEKC_ID has multiple Pits and TANS, so if you have only have one pit for everry healthcheck, the query gets lot easier

Comment: PIT and TRANS to Health Check is 1:1 (I don't think the Intellij generated schema picture reflects what's there). I am not sure about using a Auto generated ID as a chronological sequence (could they get out of orderf?)

Comment: generally no, but as always there are exception, but are you sure that you have a 1:1 becasue than ypu don't need he row_number at all and join them with any subselect

Comment: Yes its 1:1 (optional) - public class PIT [     @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = true)
    private HealthCheck healthCheck;....

Comment: then use my second query, which is as i said much easier

Comment: Actually 1:1 join version doesn't work when PIT is not on the newest HealthCheck. Ditto for Transmitter.

Comment: There is no relation between bird and pit. As long as you don't add. Column birdie and use the first query but instead .of health I'd join by bird I'd, but your question was correctly answered for your design

Comment: First query generates SQL error. If I join PIT and TRANS to BIRD then how would I know which health check they were created in? Should there be two relationships for PIT and TRANS? One relationship to bird and one to healthcheck?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244147/discussion-between-ray-bond-and-nbk).

Answer (score 0):

For each bird (left join) to return a result set containing:

- Newest health check (by date)
- Recursively getting newest PIT (determined by date from related health check)
- Recursively getting newest Trans (determined by date from related health check)

Noting that the PIT and Trans are often not on the newest Health Check can be done by:

```
SELECT *
  FROM BIRD AS b
  LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT *
          FROM (
                SELECT id AS hc_id, bird_id, catch_date
                     , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY bird_id ORDER BY catch_date DESC) AS n
                  FROM HEALTH_CHECK
               ) AS cte1a
         WHERE n = 1
     ) AS cte1
    ON cte1.bird_id = b.id
  LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT *
          FROM (
                SELECT p.id AS pit_id
                     , hc.bird_id
                     , p.Health_Check_Id
                     , p.code
                     , hc.catch_date as catchdate
                     , RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY hc.bird_id ORDER BY catch_date DESC) AS n
                  FROM PIT          AS p
                  JOIN HEALTH_CHECK AS hc  
                    ON p.Health_Check_Id = hc.id
               ) AS cte2a
         WHERE n = 1
     ) AS cte2
    ON cte2.bird_id = b.id
  LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT *
          FROM (
                SELECT t.id AS transmitter_id
                     , hc.bird_id
                     , t.Health_Check_Id
                     , t.channel
                     , hc.catch_date as catchdate
                     , RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY hc.bird_id ORDER BY catch_date DESC) AS n
                  FROM TRANSMITTER          AS t
                  JOIN HEALTH_CHECK AS hc  
                    ON t.Health_Check_Id = hc.id
               ) AS cte3a
         WHERE n = 1
```

A fiddle is [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=70ac44d360f7c41ac5db8b29f116e90c).